# Get the inner Html by Html agility in C#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

In this example:How do I get the inner text but not getting the link tag()

[the example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHept.png)

Comment: Please [post code, not pictures of code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery:

$(".twitter-timeline-link").text();

Comment: @Payam Alavi is that what you want tto get?

Comment: thank you so much my friend but I wanted to use html-agility-pack.